# How to make a MPEG-DASH MPD which starts the playback in the middle of the first segment?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, mpeg-dash, mp4box

Here are the reproduce steps:

1. Normalize an H.264 video stream

   ***ffmpeg -i 2.h264 -c:v libx264 -intra -r 25 -vf scale=640x360,setdar=16:9 2@25fps@intra@640x360.h264***

   (*) After that, I got an H.264 stream where all pictures are H.264 IDR frames, and fps is 25, resolution is 640x360, aspect-ratio is 16:9.
2. Generate an MP4 file

   ***MP4Box -add 2@25fps@intra@640x360.h264:timescale=1000 -fps 25 2@25fps@intra@640x360.mp4***
3. Make dash MP4 fragmented content, including init mp4, .m4s files and one .mpd file

   ***MP4Box -dash 5000 -frag 5000 -dash-scale 1000 -frag-rap -segment-name 'seg_second$Number$' -segment-timeline -profile live 2@25fps@intra@640x360.mp4***
4. Copy and publish all these files to a folder under one HTTPD server
5. I want to play from 4s of the first segment, and don't display any frames before 4s, so I changed the .MPD file to modify the fields "SegmentTemplate@presentationTimeOffset", "SegmentTimeline:S@d/t", like as:
   `<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <MPD xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" minBufferTime="PT1.500S" type="static" mediaPresentationDuration="PT0H0M26.000S" maxSegmentDuration="PT0H0M5.000S" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011">
   <Period duration="PT0H0M26.000S">
   <AdaptationSet segmentAlignment="true" maxWidth="640" maxHeight="360" maxFrameRate="25" par="16:9" lang="und">
     <SegmentTemplate presentationTimeOffset="4000" media="seg_second$Number$.m4s" timescale="1000" startNumber="1" initialization="seg_secondinit.mp4">
       <SegmentTimeline>
           <S d="1000" t="4000"/>
           <S d="5000" r="4"/>
       </SegmentTimeline>
      </SegmentTemplate>
    <Representation id="1" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc3.64101E" width="640" height="360" frameRate="25" sar="1:1" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="2261831">
    </Representation>
   </AdaptationSet>
   </Period>
   </MPD>`
6. Play the MPD url from VLC player, or Edge browser, it always starts the the first frame of the first segment, the frames between 0s ~ 4s are also displayed unexpectedly.

What's wrong with my steps? Or any other options for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already clarified!
It works well in Shakaplayer, but it does not work in Edge browser and VLC player.